# Does anyone have any idea about BEAM - Blackberry Enterprise Application Middleware?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I am trying to make an application which uses the features in the upcoming BEAM ? Does anyone have any idea how to get started with this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite it was announced in 2010 I am not able to find any documentation/API on this. As well as no BEAM SDK publicly available at RIM site for download (despite I am logged in as a developer). I am under impression the SDK/API is still under progress.

BTW, have you tried to regiter here:
[Register to be notified about BlackBerry Enterprise Application Middleware features, functionality and SDK availability](https://www.blackberry.com/profile/?eventId=5005&choice=middleware) ? Just a guess - maybe upon registration you'll be provided with some useful info on this.